# How to close pipe on ctrl+C?

Tags: c, signals, pipe

How can I make sure that a pipe is closed when my C program is stopped by a SIGINT?

Comment: The OS will close all open filehandles when your process dies. What is your problem exactly?

Comment: @Mat: My pipe to `gnuplot -persist` seem to persist after forcing the program to close.

Comment: The `persist` option is exactly for that - the display process remains after main gnuplot process has died. Closing the pipe to the main process kills it, but not the displayed graph.

Comment: @Mat: Oops, you are right. I put `-persist` in there before I had the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [signal handling](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/signal_handling.html) for that:

```
#include <signal.h>

void sigHandler(int sig) { 
  // Respond to the signal here.
}

int main(..) {
  signal(SIGINT, &sigHandler);
  ..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- If you handle the SIGINT, you could just call close(). Or you could choose to keep things as they are, and keep the pipe open.
- If you don't handle the signal, you program will vanish, and its side of the pipe will automatically be closed by the OS. The other side of the pipe will get an EPIPE or a readreturn of zero or -1.